# How to assign a output list to ListView in c# 3 layered architecture

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, linq

I am working on one application which has a three layer architecture using EF Code First module.

1. UI Layer (UI)
2. Business Logic Layer (BLL)
3. Data Access Layer (DAL)

Using LINQ I am retrieving the data from database in DAL and passing it to BLL and from BLL to UI

Ex.

In DAL

```
    public object ReadUsers()
    {
        var users = db.Users.Select(u => new { u.UserName, u.IsDisable, u.FullName, u.Descriprion }).ToList();
        return users;
    }
```

in BLL

```
    public object ReadUsers()
    {
        return _userDAL.ReadUsers();
    }
```

and in UI - Assigning the list of Users to `ListView`

```
        var users = _userBLL.ReadUsers();
        users.ToList()
            .ForEach(x => lvUserRoleGroup.Items.Add(
                new ListViewItem(
                    new string[] { x.UserName, x.IsDisable.ToString(), x.FullName, x.Descriprion }))
                );
```

But it is throwing an error

> Error  1   'object' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can anyone tell me how to show the output in `ListView`? It is working fine with `DataGridView` as below -

```
        var users = _userBLL.ReadUsers();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = users;
```

Comment: Why not create a `Type` users and return a generic collection of that Type rather than passing an object? Your error is at ` users.ToList()` line cz you can't call `ToList()` on an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are returning `users` from your methods,it **casts** to `object`.So when you call ToList() method,in `object`'s reference there is not that method.You must **cast it back** to your object's type.And because you have anonymous type,you need to create your custom class with fields `x.UserName, x.IsDisable.ToString(), x.FullName, x.Descriprion` and everywhere instead of **anonymous type** use your **Custom Type** and then cast to that object of `List<CustomClass>`

Or change `objects` like this

This will be your class

```
class CustomClass
{
   public string UserName {get ;set ;}
   public bool IsDisable  {get ;set ;}
   public string FullName {get ;set ;}
   public string Description {get ;set ;}
}
```

**In DAL**

```
public List<CustomClass> ReadUsers()
{
        var users = db.Users.Select(u => new CustomClass{ UserName = u.UserName, IsDisable = u.IsDisable, FullName = u.FullName, Description u.Descriprion }).ToList();
        return users;
}
```

**in BLL**

```
public List<CustomClass> ReadUsers()
{
    return _userDAL.ReadUsers();
}
```

**and in UI - Assigning the list of Users to ListView**

```
List<CustomClass> users = _userBLL.ReadUsers();

            users.ForEach(x => lvUserRoleGroup.Items.Add(
                new ListViewItem(
                    new string[] { x.UserName, x.IsDisable.ToString(), x.FullName, x.Descriprion }))
                );
```

Comment: Hi Suren - I have a class `User` already for these fields when I use `List<User>` and return `users` it says >Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<User>'

Comment: @Rajendra what it says ?

Comment: As well as I need to import the reference of Data (`User` class) to BLL layer that I guess violates the rule of 3 layered architecture, not sure. I have a different projects for UI(Winform), BLL(Class Library), DAL(Class Library) and Data(Class Library)

Comment: For first error.You are still using anonymous type.change it to User type(I show in my code).For second I can't say anything because I don't see your code.I think you must add it into your Data

Comment: To share the user object between classes, create an interfaces project and an `IUser` interface.  Use the interface between layers. `IList<IUser>`.

Comment: Thanks pilotcam, I am new to interfaces don't know how to use. Can you guide me with some examples. How to use the interfaces between UI, BLL and DAL layers?

Answer (score -1):

Add a reference to System.Linq to the failing project.

Comment: error must be happening at `users.ToList()` line because `users` is an object and you can't call `ToList()` on an object. Importing `System.Linq` will not help.

Comment: System.Linq isn't assembly and can't be added as reference. It's namespace. And assembly that contains is - `System.Core`